# Haskell loop and local variable

Tags: haskell, for-loop, equivalent

I just started learning Haskell and I do not understand how to write the equivalent of such a program in the Haskell in which there are loops and local variables in it. Can anyone suggest how such a program would look at Haskell? How to replace the second cycle, because it involves the local variables?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int n;
int a [100];
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    cin >> a[i];
}

int max = 0;
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i ++) {
    if (a[i+1] - a[i] > max) {
        max = a[i+1] + a[i];
        index = i;
    }
}

cout << index << endl;

return 0;

}
```

My attempts to write code in Haskell:

```
module MyProgram where 

import Data.List
import Data.Ord

-- Getting a new modernized list

f :: Int a => [a] -> [a]
f x = zipWith (-) (tail x) (x)
```

Now I just need to run through the list and find the maximum element and store its index. I understand how to do it in C and Java and gave the example above, how would I have implemented, but in Haskell because there are no cycles. Need recursion?

My main difficulty lies in the fact that I do not understand what design in Haskell can replace me with a cycle variables within it. I was looking for information on the Internet, but could not find anything comprehensible to me.

Comment: Can you show your Haskell attempt ? People will be able to help you better if they understand what you have tried.

Comment: Yes, of course, I am now add code

Comment: `Int a => [a] -> [a]` is invalid. Either you meant `Integral a =>` or `Ord a =>` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to get a list of differences between the elements. Let's look at your try:

```
f x = zipWith (-) (tail x) x
```

Now if we used recursion, we could define it like this:

```
findMax :: [Int] -> Int
findMax list = helper 0 -1 minusInfinity $ zipWith (-) (tail list) list
  where
    helper _            maxIndex _          []          = maxIndex
    helper currentIndex maxIndex currentMax (elem:list)
      | elem > currentMax = helper (currentIndex + 1) currentIndex elem list
      | otherwise = helper (currentIndex + 1) maxIndex currentMax list
    minusInfinity = minBound :: Int -- the smallest element possible
```

But somehow recursion is rather ugly and verbose. Let's see if we can do better:

`f` already generates the correct subtraction list.

Now you want to associate each element with it's index. In Haskell, combining information can easily be done with a tuple `(Int, Int)` using `zip`:

```
zip [0..] list = [(0, 1st element), (1, 2nd element), ..]
```

The element you want to consider is now the right part of a tuple, accessible by `snd`:

```
snd (index, elem) == elem
```

Using the function `maximumBy`, we now get:

```
g x = maximumBy (comparing snd) $ zip [0..] $ f x
```

`maximumBy (comparing snd)` means "getting the maximum element by `comparing` the `snd` part of each tuple". This now returns the tuple `(index, element)` where `element` is maximal. To access the first element of a tuple, we can use:

```
fst (index, element) == index
```

So the entire function can be written as:

```
f x = fst $ maximumBy (comparing snd) $ zip [0..] $ zipWith (-) (tail x) x
```

Which is way more elegant than the recursive formula above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
import Data.List

calc :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a
calc = snd . foldl (\(max,index) (x,y) -> if (y-x) > max then (y+x,index) else (max,index + 1) ) (0,-1) . helper

helper :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
helper x = zip (tail x) (init x)
```

`helper` builds up a list of successive pairs of elements. Then, `calc` does the comparison and other manipulations from your imperative loop. The accumulator is a tuple consisting of your local variables `max` and `index`. Since you only need the index at the end, we use `snd` to get that part out. Notice that we represent the input as a tuple as well to make it easier to work with.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FVEN35934)